# Resolve mac address by host name

Tags: python, perl, ip, mac-address, hostname

I've wrote several perl scripts during my internship, and I would like to simplify the use of them. The scripts asks in arg, a mac address, and returns which switch is connected, speed...etc.
Instead of giving a mac address, I would like to give a host name of a computer. So, how can I resolve the hostname to mac address ?
Thanks, bye.

Edit -> Solution could be : bash command or perl module or something powerfull like that...

Comment: What's the scope of this script? How large is the network, hosts and switches? You're accessing switch information, so are you a network administrator?

Comment: @MattH : This script localize a mac address in the company. Network is about 20 cisco switch (2960 mainly), and about 500 computers, maybe more. I'm not admin, I'm here for my internship, I ask infos to switchs in SNMP (with Perl). To simplify script for others, I wrote CGI, to display in a browser, and I would like to enter PC name instead of mac address.

Comment: Do the hosts pick up their IPs via DHCP? If so, there may already be an IP/MAC database at your company. Do you have access to the router(s) ARP table via SNMP too?

Comment: how many different subnets will you need to poll for mac-addresses?  Keep in mind that the solution I offered below is only good for the subnet that your server is connected to

Comment: @MattH, @Mike Pennington : Ok guys, I see. The network admin gave me an export of the dhcp (.csv). So I can resolve host name -> mac (-> ip). Thx guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ arp -an
? (4.121.8.3) at 08:00:27:f5:5b:6b [ether] on eth0
? (4.121.8.4) at 08:00:27:f5:5b:6b [ether] on eth0
? (4.121.8.1) at 00:1b:53:6b:c9:c4 [ether] on eth0
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

In python...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import re

def parse_arpline(line, hosts):
    match = re.search(r'\((\S+?)\)\s+at\s+(\S+)', line)
    if match is not None:
        ipaddr = match.group(1)
        mac = match.group(2)
        hosts.append((ipaddr, mac))
    return hosts

SUBNET = '192.168.1.0/24'  # Insert your subnet here
subprocess.Popen([r"nmap","-sP", SUBNET],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
p = subprocess.Popen([r"arp","-an"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')
hosts = []
ii = 0
for line in p:
    hosts = parse_arpline(line, hosts)
    ii +=1
# Iterate and do something with the hosts list
print hosts
```

in perl...

```
my $SUBNET = '192.168.1.0/24';  # Insert your subnet here
`nmap -sP $SUBNET`;
my $p = `arp -an`;
for my $line (split('\n', $p)) {
    $line=~/\((\S+?)\)\s+at\s+(\S+)/;
    $ipaddr = $1;
    $mac = $2;
    # do something with with each mac and ip address
}
```

Comment: @eouti, what about the `arp` command doesn't help for 500 computers?

Comment: @eouti, you have a bizarre manner of interacting with people who try to help you

Comment: the `arp` cache will only be populated with hosts for which the local host has interacted with (and cached the response of an ARP lookup).  If the host(s) you are interested in are not in the cache, you will need to generate an ARP request.

Comment: @jmtd, good point... he will need to run `nmap -sP <subnet_addr>` before running the arp

Comment: Thanks guys, cool for your help, srry Mike, didn't want to be nasty.

Answer (score 0):

The `ethers` file on a UNIX system maps Ethernet address to IP-number (or hostname).  If your `/etc/ethers` is properly maintained, you can look it up in there.

Comment: Thx, but mine is not properly maintained, empty file.

Comment: That's properly maintained then.